# Hash tables for storing data in an application that supports partial search

Tags: data-structures, hash, database-theory, hash-tables

Is a hash table a good data structure for storing data in an application that support partial search such as "select * from MyTable where name like 'John%'.  If not, what is?

I would have thought that hash table isnt ideal because there no way to make faster than O(n). Maybe a some kind of balanced binary tree best. However, I am not sure that it would be best for the particular query above.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  Have you tried to figure out how to implement such queries?  This seems like a good test of your understanding of hashtables and what operations they support.  You should be able to answer this on your own if you understand how hashtables work, so I suggest spending some more time to try to solve this on your own, then [edit] the question to show your thoughts and what prevents you from answering it on your own, so we understand your current level of understanding.

Comment: @D.W. edited now

Comment: So what question do you want answered?  The question you articulate is whether a hash table is good, and you seem to have answered your own question.  Is your real question what data structure would be a good choice for these queries?  If so, please [edit] your question to ask that question instead.